# Can Trulia tables be scraped using only scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I looking for the content of this kind of tables:

http://www.trulia.com/school-district/CA-San_Francisco_County/San_Francisco_Unified/

I can get the rows by:

```
rows = response.xpath('//*[@id="middle_tab_content"]/table/tr[]').extract()
```

The problem is that there are several pages in the tables keep the same link

```
http://www.trulia.com/school-district/CA-San_Francisco_County/San_Francisco_Unified/
```

And the rows also keep the same Xpath, there's no change in the table

Edit.

@Salman: I see the Network tab but can't find the XHR subtab

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next pages are being fetched using `XMLHttpRequest`. If you inspect the page in your browser you will find the url for that request. For the second page it looks like this:

```
http://www.trulia.com/q_schools_in_district.php?did=600116051&grade=elementary&page=2&sortby=testRating&sortdir=desc
```

What you can do is to scrape one page and then request the next page using the this url. You can get each page simply by replacing the page number in `&page=<page>` query.

Comment: How did you get the address? it's in "inspect element" I'm using chrome.

Comment: Go to `Network` tab and then `XHR` sub-tab. Here you can see the `xhr` requests.

Comment: I see the Network tab but  can't find the XHR subtab

Comment: Also, when I try: scrapy shell http://www.trulia.com/q_schools_in_district.php?did=600116051&grade=elementary&page=2&sortby=testRating&sortdir=desc  it doesn't work

Comment: The `XHR` and some other tabs are filters. You have to enable it. Click the cone shaped icon at the top left side. 2nd to the left from the red icon.